# Can you listen for `on{custom-event}` when you emit Custom Events in JS?

Tags: javascript

In JS, you can `elem.addEventListener('click', ()...)` and you can also `elem.onclick(() => //do stuff)`. Can you do the same for custom events? I have a custom event like so:

```
 function emitEvent() {
    const event = new CustomEvent("option_removed", {
      bubbles: true,
    });
    selectBox.dispatchEvent(event);
  }
```

Does registering a new CustomEvent allow you to also do `elem.onoption_removed(function() {do stuff?})`  or is that only for native browser events?

Comment: `onclick` ([and others](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#handler-onclick)) only work because they are defined by the spec. Hence custom events won't work.

Comment: That's what I thought - just wanted to see if there was any way to "passively" listen for events instead of adding a new event listener.